# how to space a text with tick icon on button on mobile view

Tags: html, css, button

button with tick box in mobile view

[image]

Please can someone help in how to space the "Yes Please" from the arrow correctly in mobile view thank you.

```css
.wrapper {
  margin-left: -$spacing-fixed-1;
  margin-right: -$spacing-fixed-1;
  display: flex;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

button {
  margin: 0 $spacing-fixed-1 0 $spacing-fixed-1;
  max-width: calc(50% - #{$spacing-fixed-2});
}
```

Comment: Please click [edit], then `[<>]` sippet editor and provide a [mcve]

Comment: Please click [edit], scroll down and click "edit above snippet" and add relevant HTML

Answer (score 0):

Are tick and "Yes please" in different divs? If yes you just have to give to the left div some margin right.
If you're in a flex you can set `justify-content: space-between` to the parent div.